# Now that Android 4.0 is out, is Multi Touch possible in android emulator?

Tags: android, maps, multi-touch, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

There are similar questions like this uptill Android 2.3 sdk on Stackoverflow. But as per the answers it was not supported back then. I have even seen a [feature request ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5977) for it with Google but it is still pending!

With the recent release of 4.0 sdk, does any one know if it is now possible to simulate the multi-touch  feature in the emulator? If yes, please do information on how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multitouch in the emulator is still unsupported and has not been announced as a planned feature.  This would most likely come as an update to the SDK tools and not the operating system itself so the [Android Tools recent changes feed](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent) is probably the best place to follow for any news on this feature.