# Simulate Multi Touch in Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

Is there any way to simulate Multi touch feature in Android Emulator ?

Comment: duplicate of questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884362/how-to-test-multi-touch-in-android-emulator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931458/now-that-android-4-0-is-out-is-multi-touch-possible-in-android-emulator and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825505/is-there-any-way-to-test-muti-touch-on-android-emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to test multi-touch on the Android Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825505/is-there-any-way-to-test-multi-touch-on-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Multi-touch is not supported in the android  emulator. There is an open issue in the Android issue tracker for multi touch support in the emulator. It's not accepted by Google but you can start it.